# document.write("anything") does not execute in internet explorer as an external script

Tags: javascript

my javascript file only executes as an internal style, when linked as an external style, it fails to execute. I am previewing the webpage in internet explorer.. however it executes in chrome whether as an inline or external javascript file.

here is my html:
*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="script.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wwd">
<a class="link1" href="URL">What We do</a>
</div>
<div class="wwd_content">
<p id="ss">Sell Shoes</p>
<p id="sc">Sell Cars</p>
<p id="sp">Sell Pets</p>
<p id="si">Sell Interiors</p>
</div>
<div class="acp">
<a class="link2" href="URL">ACP standards</a>
</div>
<div class="qg">
<a class="link3" href="URL">Quality guarantee</a>
</div>
<div class="nav_bar">
<h3 id="home">Home</h3>
<h3 id="products">Products</h3>
<h3 id="services">Services</h3>
<h3 id="contact">Contact Us</h3>
</div>
<div class="logo">
<h1> DW </h1>
<p>Demwu International</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my javascript:

```
document.write("new web page");
```

Comment: Is it in the `<head>` or the `<body>`.

Comment: Please show the HTML that loads the external JS, not the script that has inline JS.

Comment: Don't do that. Don't use document.write. Don't try to insert HTML in your head tag.

Comment: @Barmar this is my code with the external style

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="style.js">
</script>

</head>

<body>

Comment: @ShaeYi Edit the question to show the actual code.

Comment: @Barmar no problem, I have edited my code to show external javascript

Comment: There's not any standard for invalid HTML (non-metadata content in [`head`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head)) parsing. Browsers can handle it in any way they want/can, and IE is especially poor, what comes to invalid HTML parsing. A quick-fix would be to move the script to the `body`.

Comment: I just tried creating a new html page with an external javascript and it works on this page?? dunno why it works when I create a new html.. there must be something in my code that Internet explorer does not like

Comment: Non-printing characters in the `src` attribute of the original file? Incorrect URL?

Comment: it works now, all I had to do was create a new document and save as a different name from original html file, and my javascript now executes.. thanks to all who contributed

Answer (score 0):

This is because your script is executed even before the dom is initialized. Keep the script tag after closing body. Before that you can type "`javascript:document.write("<h1>new web page</h1>")`" , without start and end quotes in your address bar and press enter

Comment: "... script is executed even before the dom is initialized." Yes, that's exactly the idea of `document.write()` ...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I also realized that I didn't get the question properly.